# hot reload needs to be done for app to run

Tags: flutter, dart, hot-reload

I am working on a Flutter app that uses Firebase and a Stream to show a list view if the data in Firebase is != null. If the data is null, I have my code display a loading sign. Whenever I launch my app, to begin with, the loading symbol is the first thing to come up and doesn't go away until I hot reload my app. When I hot restart again, I need to hot reload for the data to show up. If I ever publish my app will this issue come up for users or is it only because I am in Debug mode in my simulator? If this is an issue that may come up when the app is published, does anyone know how to fix this?

code:

```dart
  Widget MemoirsList() {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: memoirsStream != null
          ? Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                StreamBuilder(
                  stream: memoirsStream,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return MemoirsCard(
                            authorName: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['authorName'],
                            title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data["title"],
                            description: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['description'],
                            imgUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['imgURL'],
                          );
                        });
                  },
                )
              ],
            )
          : Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely related to the Debug mode. I've been facing this issue a lot too. Try to build it in release mode and it should work fine.  The app size of a debug build is large due to the debugging overhead that allows for hot reload and source level debugging.

When building a release version of your app, consider using the `--split-debug-info` tag. This tag can dramatically reduce code size. For an example of using this tag, see [Obfuscating Dart code](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/obfuscate).

Other things you can do to make your app smaller are:

- Remove unused resources
- Minimize resource imported from libraries
- Support a limited number of screen densities
- Compress PNG and JPEG files

[To build a release version for Android](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

[To build a release version for IOS](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios)